# Making an embedded Flash not stop when a Greybox overlay is opened on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, greybox

I'm working on a band website that has a Flash-based music player always visible. The idea is that the user can listen to the band's song as he is browsing through the site.

This has been working nicely, but in the weekend I started to work on a Greybox-based gallery for the site and ran into a serious issue. When an image is opened into the full Greybox view on top of the flash, the music stops. In fact, you can see through the overlay that the music player disappears completely until the Greybox overlay is closed. After the overlay is closed, you can select and play a track again.

This problem happens at least with newest Chrome and Firefox 5. For some reason, IE8 plays the track on the background fine.

Now, what could be causing this, and more importantly is there anything I can do to fix it? Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a FYI for those who might run into the same issue, Lightbox2 Lite did not have this issue (regular Lightbox did, though) and worked out of the box. This was in Drupal but I'd imagine the same applies elsewhere as well.